# Objective-C visibleCells and indexPathsForVisibleRows

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsindexpath

How do I read intValue of an array of NSIndexpaths through indexPathsForVisibleRows?

By the way, why do visibleCells and indexPathsForVisibleRows not work before if (cell == nil) function?

Here is my code:

In the cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
    static NSString *identifierString;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifierString];

    // when I use visibleCells and indexPathsForVisibleRows here, the app crashes

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:identifierString] autorelease];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;          
    }

    // when I use visibleCells and indexPathsForVisibleRows here, the app works

//cell implementation here

    return cell;
```

Comment: It feels like a lot of context is missing for the second part of the question. Could you please post some code where `if (cell == nil)` is?

Comment: How do you read their values when it works? What is it you are trying to do in this method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is where the tableview gets populated with cells. If you try to reference visible cells before they have been created, which is done within the if-statement, then the app crashes.
The `alloc` command allocated memory for the cell to be created and then it gets initialized with certain parameters. This method gets called as many times as you designate in `numberOfRowsInSection`.

So that you don't recreate all the cells again and again the if-statement checks if the cell does exist and only if it is nil creates a new one to take the place.

To get the `int` row value of an IndexPath you can use it's row property. For example:

```
NSArray indexArray = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
int i=0;
while(i!=indexArray.count){
   //Log out the int value for the row
   NSLog(@"%d", indexArray[i].row);
   i++;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: row not found in indexArray[i].row